# Replacing complex-valued arguments of generic function object by two real-valued arguments

Tags: python, generics

Curve fitting tools such as those in [scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) tend to assume that the parameters of the model functions are real-valued.
When fitting a model that depends on complex-valued parameters to a complex-valued data set, one therefore first has to create a version of the model, in which each complex parameter is replaced by two real ones.

First, a simple example:

```
# original function, representing a model where a,b may be complex-valued
def f(x, a, b):
    return a+b*x

# modified function, complex parameters have been replaced by two real ones
def f_r(x, a_r, a_i, b_r, b_i):
    return f(x, a_r + 1J*a_i, b_r+1J*b_i)

print( f(1,2+3J,4+5J) == f_r(1,2,3,4,5) )
```

*Note:* The output of the model is still complex-valued, but this can easily be taken care of by appropriately defining the residual function.

Now, instead of having to write new code for every function `f`, I would like to have a "function factory" to which I pass the function object `f` together with a list of booleans `is_complex` specifying which arguments of `f` are to be assumed complex-valued (and therefore need to be replaced by two real-valued arguments).
This list of booleans could e.g. be inferred from the initial values provided together with `f`.

I am new to this kind of problem, so I looked around on the web and came across the [decorator module](http://pythonhosted.org/decorator/documentation.html). Before going to the generic case, here is the example from above using the `Functionmaker` class:

```
import decorator

def f(x, a, b):
    return a+b*x

f_r = decorator.FunctionMaker.create(
    'f_r(x, a_r, a_i, b_r, b_i)',
    'return f(x, a_r + 1J*a_i, b_r + 1J*b_i)',
    dict(f=f))
```

For the generic case, one can now imagine to synthesize the two strings that are passed to the function maker:

```
import decorator
import inspect

def f(x, a, b):
    return a+b*x

def fmaker(f,is_complex):
    argspec = inspect.getargspec(f)
    args = argspec.args[:]
    fname = f.func_name

    s1 = "{}_r(".format(fname)
    s2 = "return f("
    for arg, cplx in zip(args, is_complex):
        if not cplx:
            s1 += "{},".format(arg)
            s2 += "{},".format(arg)
        else:
            s1 += "{}_r,".format(arg)
            s1 += "{}_i,".format(arg)
            s2 += "{}_r+1J*{}_i,".format(arg,arg)

    s1 += ')'
    s2 += ')'
    return decorator.FunctionMaker.create(s1,s2,dict(f=f))

is_complex = [False, True, True]
f_r = fmaker(f,is_complex)

# prints ArgSpec(args=['x', 'a_r', 'a_i', 'b_r', 'b_i'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=())
print(inspect.getargspec(f_r)) 
print( f(1,2+3J,4+5J) == f_r(1,2,3,4,5) )
```

This seems to solve the problem.

My question is: is this a reasonable way of doing this? Are there better/simpler ways in python?

P.S. I am not a computer scientist, so if I am using technical terms incorrectly, please feel free to revise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to do any nasty string based generation, you can simply use basic function closures to create a wrapper:

```
def complex_unroll(f, are_complex):

    # This function will have access to are_complex and f through python closure
    # *args give us access to all parameters as a list
    def g(*args, **kwargs):
        # new_args stores new list of parameters, the complex ones
        new_args = []
        # arg_id is iterator used to keep track where are we in the original list
        arg_id = 0
        for is_complex in are_complex:        
            if is_complex:
                # if we request complex unroll, we merge two consequtive params
                new_args.append(args[arg_id] + 1J*args[arg_id+1])
                # and move iterator 2 slots
                arg_id += 2
            else:
                # otherwise, just copy the argument
                new_args.append(args[arg_id])
                arg_id += 1
        # finally we return a call to original function f with new args
        return f(*new_args, **kwargs)

    # our unroll function returns a newly designed function g
    return g
```

And now

```
def f(x, a, b):
    return a+b*x

def f_r(x, a_r, a_i, b_r, b_i):
    return f(x, a_r + 1J*a_i, b_r+1J*b_i)

f_u = complex_unroll(f, [False, True, True])

print f(1,2+3J,4+5J)
print f_r(1,2,3,4,5)
print f_u(1,2,3,4,5)

f_u2 = complex_unroll(f, [True, True, True])

print f_u2(1,0,2,3,4,5)
```

Works as desired.

Why I would prefer this path as compared to the proposed one in the question?

- It does not use **any** additional modules/libraries, just a very basic mechanism of python's dealing with arguments and closures. In particular your solution does reflection, it analyzes the defined function, which is quite complex operation as compared to what you try to obtain.
- It handles named arguments just fine, so if you have `f(x, a, b, flag)`, you can still just use `g = complex_unroll(f, [False, True, True])` and call `g(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, flag = True)`, which would fail in your code. You could add support for this, though.

Comment: Thank you, this solution is indeed much easier (upvote will display later). Could you comment on the speed of evaluation of your function `f_u2` (which, admittedly, was not part of my question)? The only possible disadvantage I can see here is the overhead of constructing the new argument list each time the function `f_u2` is called (and it may be called very often, when one is solving an optimization problem).

Comment: the overhead, in case of both my and yours solution is pretty much the same - additional jump, as we have a function that calls a function. In case of f_u2 vs. f_u it should be very small, as the overhead will come from memory allocation only, which has to be smaller than any reasonable operation inside f itself (like defining local variable). Thus I would say, that if you are looking for efficiency, you have bigger "bites" to take than this one - like going for cython for any single loop in your evaluation instead of python. However, if you have lots of parameters, my solution might be slow.